# Classic ASP app not working in IIS 8.5

Tags: iis, asp-classic, iis-8

I've moved my classic asp app to win 2012 R2 (IIS 8.5). This app uses **COM** component. I've registered this component using `regsvr32` and also exported older components from II 6 to II 8.5. I can see those components in control *pane->component* services.

This app is not working properly. Code include `Server.CreateObject("myCOM");` looks like it works but when I try to get `objArgs["prop1"];` it doesn't work.

I see this error:

> "Server.CreateObject failed while checking permissions. Access is
>   denied to this object."

What could be potential issue?

PS: I've installed ASP/server side includes & others.

Comment: Belongs on: http://serverfault.com/

Comment: @Diodeus why? COM objects are integral part of classic ASP development, and this could be anything from IIS config (which is *definitely* programming-related) to a source problem.

Comment: This is a server config issue, not a coding problem.

Answer (score 0):

What are the permissions on the DLL set to? That is, can the user that IIS is running as access the file?

Did you register it as both 32- and 64-bit?

Can you create the object from a test VB script (running from an elevated command prompt, creating from a VBS script or a PowerShell script)?

"Access Denied" usually means exactly what it says on the tin. I'd guess that the IIS user (or that used by the app pool for your site) doesn't have correct permissions on the DLL.

Comment: David, I exported COM components from source and install on win 2k12 R2. Additionally, I registered using regsvr32. I've enabled 32bit application,.net CLR=4 & managed pipeline=Classic for app in IIS. What shall I do next?

Comment: The IUSR account associated with your website, (you can find out what it's called by right clicking on your webiste root folder on the server and select Properties > Security) may need execute permission on the dll for your COM component

Answer (score 0):

I am having similar problem trying to run an ASP site using ASPMail with PGP on Windows 2012R2. The mailer runs fine, and PGP works if I run it inside PowerShell, but the mailer can no longer use its PGP option, which is running pgp.exe from inside an ASP page.

Answer (score 0):

Turn on ASP from Internet Information Services -> World Wide Web Services -> Application Devlopment Features -> ASP.